# Maintaining single object or passing the context in python command pattern

Tags: python, command-pattern

I am trying to maintain a single copy of agentbook object in SCHEDULE, CANCEL, and other commands.

but with below code, is maintaining separate objects for different commands is there a way to fix this

I tried to pass the context in execute method it dint work
the methods are in agentBook class

```html
class AgentBook:

class ICommand(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractclassmethod
    def execute():
        pass


class Schedule(ICommand):
    def __init__(self, agentBook):
        self.__agentBook = agentBook

    def execute(self):
        self.__agentBook.schedule()


class Cancel(ICommand):
    def __init__(self, agentBook):
        self.__agentBook = agentBook

    def execute(self):
        self.__agentBook.cancel()


  
class Book:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__commands = {}

    def register(self, commandName, command):
        self.__commands[commandName] = command

    def execute(self, commandName):
        if commandName in self.__commands:
            self.__commands[commandName].execute()
        else:
            print('command not found')


def commandMenu():
    # reciever
    agentBook = AgentBook('Priyanka')
    SCHEDULE = Schedule(agentBook)
    CANCEL = Cancel(agentBook)
    STATUS = Status(agentBook)
    SAVE = Save(agentBook)

    # invoker
    book = Book()
    # register
    book.register("Schedule", SCHEDULE)
    book.register("Cancel", CANCEL)

    print('use following commands for respective action')
    print("Schedule")
    print("Cancel")
    
    cmd = input()
    if(cmd != 'quit'):
        book.execute(cmd)
    elif(cmd == 'quit'):
        book.execute("Save")
        exit()
    commandMenu()
```

Comment: As a general rule, objects should be nouns.  Actions (verbs) should be functions or methods.  Commands should not be objects -- they don't retain any information.  They act on other things -- objects.  In your case, the book is the object.  The actions should all be methods of the Book object, or maybe to start with functions that accept Book objects.

Comment: Thank you let me try that, do I need to create new class that inturn can execute the agentBook methods using passed object ?

Comment: No.  Commands are not things, they should not be classes.  If these commands are changing things in or using the state of the Book, then they should be methods of the Book class.  Now, I don't know what "scheduling" a book might mean; if there is some separate "Schedule" object that will be keeping its own list of books, and you will be adding and removing books, then you have to decide where it makes the most sense.  And note that I'm using "Schedule" as a noun (a list of things), and not "schedule" as a verb.